# UDF not allowed in SnowPipe Definition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a Snowflake Java UDF function `snowflake_email_validation` and trying to call that function from the snowpipe.

It is throwing the error as:

> User-defined function 'SNOWFLAKE_EMAIL_VALIDATION' with language 'JAVA' is not allowed in pipe definition" .

This is my command

```
create or replace pipe emailpipe auto_ingest=true as 
  copy into TGT_EMAIL_TABLE(EMAIL, IS_VALID) 
  from (select $1,snowflake_email_validation($1) from @s3_stage) 
  on_error=continue;
```

Please help to fix this

Comment: This is currently unsupported, I'd anticipate when Java UDFs go GA this might be addressed, but in the interim you likely want to stage your data and then create a stream/task to process the data into a target table, where that process calls your Java UDF.  I hope this helps...Rich

Answer (score 0):

COPY INTO has several limitations like this, and Snowpipe can work only with COPY INTO.

Try as an alternative [the different query below](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax). It can be eventually encapsulated in a stored procedure, and called periodically on a schedule by a task.

```
create or replace table TGT_EMAIL_TABLE(EMAIL, IS_VALID) as
  select $1, snowflake_email_validation($1)
  from @s3_stage
```